# Select multiple RAILS with association editing does not select the options already marked in the creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, multi-select

Greetings I am creating a user editing form in RAILS guiding me through the basic examples of the rails page but in the creation I select 2 companies that the user has related, saves them in database, I can show them in view of the user's profile but do not mark them as selected when I'm editing the user
[Edit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Kt4.png)

I show you the relationships and how I create the form 
`<%= form_for(@usuario, as: 'user', url: update_user_path(@usuario), html: { method: :post , class: 'info m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right',multipart: true}) do |f| %>`

El select

```
<%= select('user', "company_ids", @company.all.collect {|p| [ "#{p.name}", p.id ] },{},{:multiple => true,  :class =>'form-control', :id => 'm_select2_1_validate'})%>
```

Models

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :user  
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: User, foreign_key: :own_id 
    has_attached_file :logo, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "" 
    validates_attachment_content_type :logo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: User, foreign_key: :user_id 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :company 
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  has_attached_file :signature, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: ""
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  validates_attachment_content_type :signature, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Controller User
Method

```
def edit 
        @usuario = User.find_by("id = ? AND user_id = ?",params[:id],current_user.id)
        if @usuario.nil? 
          render 'dashboard/error'
        else
          @company = Company.where own_id: current_user.id
        end
      end
```

I can not make the form take the default value that user already has in the select as it is a collection of results, please if you could guide me with this error, I have another system with the same forms but se sections and fill them with correct way I do not know what the error may be, thank you very much for your help, it's my first question in the community

Comment: I already translated it

Comment: Greetings I solved it creating the select of another form `<%= select_tag "user[company_ids]", options_from_collection_for_select(@company, "id", "name", @usuario.company_ids),:multiple => true,  :class =>'form-control', :id => 'm_select2_1_validate' %>`